# 90° Matrix Rotation Python

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

I cannot understand why retrieved value of original Matrix isn't the good one. For instance, value of Matrix[0,3] should give 3 but gives 0 so that I am unable to get the correct 90° Matrix rotation:

```
import numpy as np
x = np.matrix(np.arange(16).reshape((4,4)))
print(x)

def rotate_90(matrix):
    rot_Mat = matrix
    len = matrix.shape[0]
    # len_range = range(len)
    # rev_range = reversed(len_range)
    for i in range(0, len):
        for j in range(0, len):

            value = matrix[i,j]
            print(i , j , value)
            
            rot_Mat[j,len - i -1] = value
    print(rot_Mat)

rotate_90(x)
```

Comment: What is `Matrix[0, 3]`?

Comment: It's on line 13, I enter Matrix in the function rotate_90 and the value of matrix[0,3] is printed on line 14

Comment: @Alan try `np.rot90(x,axes=(1,0))`

Comment: Thanks @HusseinAwala !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> rot_Mat = matrix
> ```

This does not create a new array. `rot_Mat` is the *same* array as `matrix`, therefore you overwrite the values while reading them.

To create a *new* array with the same shape, use [`empty_like`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.empty_like.html):

```
rot_Mat = np.empty_like(matrix)
```